# How to calculate proper KCV value for a 3des encryption Key?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I'm trying to calculate KCV for a DES encryption.

```
$data = 'F337CE3C64E02D96C61A9EC69E051D5A';
$transport = '4B4D3733504D3735';
$encData = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, pack('H*', $transport),         
$data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

This is all fine, data gets properly encrypted.

Now I want to calculate KCV.

```
$key = 'F337CE3C64E02D96C61A9EC69E051D5A';
$zeroBytes = 00000000;
$kcv = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $zeroBytes, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
var_dump($kcv);
```

this returns wrong value : 953f34d098f996f9 and it should be (the final kcv) 53173F. What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your code: 1. Key should be binary, 2. Null bytes should be used, not integer zeros.

```
$key = pack('H*', '0123456789ABCDEF');
$data = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

$kcv = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
var_dump($kcv);
```

This outputs `D5D44FF720683D0D` as expected (KCV for key `0123456789ABCDEF` is `D5D44FF720683D0D`).

**EDIT:** In your case you need to append the first 16 characters to the end of the key to get the correct KCV:

```
$key = 'F337CE3C64E02D96C61A9EC69E051D5A';
$key .= substr($key, 0, 16);
$key = pack('H*', $key);

$data = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

$kcv = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
var_dump($kcv);
```

This outputs `53173F8B139F34FE`. See [Keying options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) for more details:

> The standards define three keying options:
>
> - Keying option 1: All three keys are independent.
> - Keying option 2: K1 and K2 are independent, and K3 = K1.
> - Keying option 3: All three keys are identical, i.e. K1 = K2 = K3.

Comment: Now *this* guy seems to be a cryptographer. :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm no cryptographer, but a quick googling says that a 3DES KCV needs to be calculated on a "string of binary zeroes", and `$zeroBytes = 00000000;` is not that.

PHP will read that as `0`, then type-juggle that into an ASCII zero character, aka `0x30`.

I think what you want is:

```
$zeroBytes = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
```

Which will give you eight NULL bytes, aka `0x00`.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. That was a good shot, but unfortunately this also gives wrong kcv ... I guess I have already tried everything and nothing seems to work.